# Newbie query about conditional statements

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and can't work out why the following doesn't work.

Can anyone advise? code below

thanks

---

```
# Make sure that the_flying_circus() returns True

print "What is your number?"
num = input()
print "What is bla?"
bla = input()

def the_flying_circus():
    if num ==4 and bla=="bla":    # Start coding here!
        return True
        print "Well done!"
        # Don't forget to indent
        # the code inside this block!
    elif num == 2 or bla== zog:
        print "OK"
        # Keep going here.
        # You'll want to add the else statement, too!
    else:
        print "Bad luck!"
the_flying_circus()
```

Comment: Is this Python 2.x? If so, use `raw_input()` instead of input. Or better yet, [download and learn the latest(stable) version of Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/win).

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not very informative. What is the code supposed to do, and what does it actually do?

Comment: you probably mean `"zog"` unless `zog` is defined as a variable elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

The `return True` is probably not what you want to have on the top of the `if` block. Try removing it.

Answer (score 0):

The only condition that will return True is num==4 and bla=='bla'. Otherwise, the return value is None. However, 'Well done!' will never be printed since the return statement occurs first.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things...

1) return True should be moved to the end of the function (as mentioned by others)

2) watch how you collect input...  use raw_input for your string, use input for the number.

This works for me:

```
def the_flying_circus():
  if a==4 and b=='bla':
    print "Well done!"
  elif a==2 or b=="zog":
    print "OK"
  else:
    print "Bad luck!"
  return 1

a = input("What is your number? ")
b = raw_input("What is bla? ")

the_flying_circus()
```